# workflows for variations in SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow, variations

I have created a site collection and implemented variations for the site collection. Now I am able to get all the lists, pages and list items that are created in the source site to target site. But while implementing workflows I am unable to get the workflow in the target list.

Can we implement the workflows which are created in the Source List to the Target List??

Note:I have implemented the workflows using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow association is probably not automatically copied with the variations mechanism.

I guess you can prove this by deleting the list in a target and then try and recreate the list with the association by using variations.

I also guess there is a difference between Sharepoint 2010 Workflows and Sharepoint 2013 Workflows and how they work with variations.

I would suggest moving the workflow into a Visual Studio solution. New variation targets could then be provisioned with a workflow association either when the list is created or the web is created.